# Django 1.6 to 1.9: /django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

Tags: python, django

I recently started working on a new site, upgraded to Django 1.9 from 1.6, and made some changes. I went to test it, and this is what I get.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://example.com/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mainapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:

File "/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

`urls.py` (it's not done, but here it is):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from mainapp import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^u\/[a-zA-Z._0-9]+', views.Index),
    url(r'^', views.Index),

]
```

Comment: really? that's it? that's the whole stack trace?

Comment: Please provide `urls.py`. Looks like something wrong with your urlpatterns.

Comment: What happens if you comment out all the middleware and run it again with one uncommented middleware at a time?

Comment: @vesche added urls.py

Comment: Is it something to do with as_view() ? See: [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/), [this common question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858494/typeerror-at-init-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given), and [this other common question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995516/django-rest-framework-init-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given). Good luck.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

you should set url pattern for your main page of project like this :

```
url(r'^$', ........)
```

for example :

```
url(r'^$',views.Main,name='main')
```

Comment: You forgot `as_view()`

Comment: I have no problem with this ... @User